# JMETER - Fetch data on response data and be a variable on API

Tags: java, jmeter

Thanks for helping!
I'm trying to get a ID from a Response Data, but i tryied everything and didn't work, let me show:

[I want that ORGKEY as a Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3pMK.png)

I run POST, after they give me a ORGKEY
And i need the ORGKEY in POST TOKEN

[POST TOKEN needs a orgKey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wywR.png)

And the orgkey are a random numbers and letters! I tryed everything but didn't work, so i try here.

Thank you for your pacient ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns this JSON response
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `ORGKEY`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$..orgKey`
   - Match No.: `1`
3. That's it, you should be able to refer the extracted value as `${ORGKEY}` where required

More information:

- [JsonPath Examples](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: Thanks! This solve that, i was working two days on that hhahahaha
This: $..orgKey solve my problem THANKS A LOOOOOOOOT <3

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response

```
{
   "result":{
      "returnCodel":"success",
      "orgKey":"3b6car5lkckvgx52wf",
      "message":"Organizaçào criada com sucesso!"
   }
}
```

You can use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMSEPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) to extract the `orgKey` from the response.

[image]

[image]